# c++ use string to store float and int

Tags: c++, string

Assume now I have to pass around a struct foo using string. The struct contains 3 pieces:
one int, one float and one string:

```
struct foo {
  int a;
  float b;
  string c;
}
```

What I decided to do is to write a simple wrapper to encode and decode this struct foo:

```
string& encode_foo(const foo &input) {
    // what do I do here?
    // declare a string and fill in 4 bytes for a, 4 bytes for b and then c?
    string ret;
    ret.append((char*)(&input.a), 4);  // This is really ugly, isn't it??
    ret.append((char*)(&input.b), 4);  // this is also very ugly??
}

foo decode_foo(const string &input) {
    // get input.c_str() and cast to int and float?
}
```

I am just curious if there's an elegant way to do this?

Comment: Look up [`std::to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string), and use a separator.

Comment: I don't want to waste more bits on that... my understanding is that std::to_string will make it much larger, suppose my float is 1.111111111, I only want to spend 4 bytes.

Comment: By putting the values directly into the string without encoding them in some way, you'll break the string. 0 is a valid value for both int and float, but is treated as a null-terminator inside a string and might break consumers of that string. Encoding will necessarily take up more bytes than the original value (since you no longer have as many valid combinations of bits left to use).

Comment: Then why not pass around the structure _as is_? If you make sure the compiler packs it without padding, then that's the smallest you're going to get.

Comment: It will also be helpful if you tell us what you need this for? _Why_ do you need to pass this around in "encoded" form?

Comment: @What - Don't know about you, but in my computer there are billions of bytes. Not using 4 of those won't help anyone.

Comment: And, if you really need to encode this in binary form, you should probably use a raw array of bytes instead of using strings. But remember if you pass this around multiple platforms that the binary representation is not the same on all platforms.

Comment: @WhatABeautifulWorld Of course your code is ugly: It involves _raw_ pointers!

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps something like:

```
struct foo {
  int a;
  float b;
  string c;
}
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const foo& f) {
    return os << f.a << " " << f.b << " " << f.c;
}
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, foo& f) {
    return is >> f.a >> f.b >> f.c;
}
std::string encode(const foo& f) {
     std::ostringstream oss;
     oss << f;
     return oss.str();
}
std::string decode(const std::string& s) {
     std::istringstream iss( s );
     foo f;
     iss >> f;
     return f;
}

int main() {
    foo f;
    std::string s=encode(f);
    f=decode(s);
}
```

The advantage of this is:

- it idiomaitc, a well know pattern
- it also allows you to easily print the value of object,  `std::cout << f`

Answer (score 1):

An option could be to use string streams to encode end decode the structure fields.
This is a simple example (but in a more realistic code you should pay attention to things like strings containing spaces, etc.):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct foo
{
    int a;
    float b;
    string c;
};

string encode_foo(const foo& f)
{
    ostringstream os;
    os << f.a << ' ' << f.b << ' ' << f.c;
    return os.str();
}

foo decode_foo(const string& s)
{
    istringstream is(s);
    foo f;
    is >> f.a;
    is >> f.b;
    is >> f.c;
    return f;
}

int main()
{
    foo f1;
    f1.a = 10;
    f1.b = 3.14f;
    f1.c = "hello";

    string s = encode_foo(f1);
    foo f2 = decode_foo(s);

    cout << f2.a << '\n' << f2.b << '\n' << f2.c << endl;
}
```

> Output:
>
> ```
> 10
> 3.14
> hello
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Look into using an [ASN.1 binary encoding like DER or PER](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_Syntax_Notation_One) or [Protocol Buffers](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/). You might also find [this table of format comparisons useful](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_data_serialization_formats).

Essentially these mark the data as "Floating Point, 4 bytes" or "Integer, 8 bytes" and then write the binary. The formats are known and standardized so that implementations can read them on any platform.

You can store these in a `std::string` because it does not actually require data to be null terminated. However, string's `c_str()` function will not work if the data contains nulls.

It would be less confusing to use a `std::vector<unsigned char>` to store bytes.

Answer (score 1):

***WARNING:*** The following code uses the endian of the current platform to mess with the data. Be careful if you're sending this to other platforms which might not have the same endian and other relevant architecture parameters.

I'm going to assume that you understand that what you're doing is *placing the 4 bytes of the float into the string's memory*, not the string representation of a float. For example, for an integer of value 2, you're putting the char values '\0', '\0', '\0', '\2' into the string. This is not the same as having '002' written out as a regular human-readable string (the first is 3 null-terminators plus a character with the decimal value of 2). You're also **directly injecting the binary representation of the float** into the string as well.

If that's what you want, then you're better of using something other than a string to store the values (`maybe a std::vector<char>` / `std::vector<unsigned char>`). For example:

```
std::vector<char>& encode_foo(const foo &input) {
    // Note that these loops, as @DeadMG pointed out in comments, can be
    // more easily accomplished with vector.insert( ... ), e.g.:
    // vector.insert(vector.end(), adata, adata + sizeof(input.a));
    std::vector<char> data;
    char* adata = (char*)&input.a;
    char* bdata = (char*)&input.b;
    char* cdata = (char*)input.c.data();
    for ( int i = 0; i < sizeof(input.a); ++i) {
        data.push_back( *adata );
        ++adata;
    }
    for ( int j = 0; j < sizeof(input.b); ++j) {
        data.push_back( *bdata );
        ++adata;
    }
    for ( int k = 0; k < input.c.length(); ++k) {
        data.push_back( *cdata );
        ++cdata;
    }

    // Now, data contains the absolute minimum binary 
    // representation of the structure
    // There are probably even simpler ways to do this, 
    // but the 3 loops are very explicit
    // And demonstrate what you want. 
    // You could consider std::copy or memcpy instead if you need
    // More flexibility.
    return data;
}

foo decode_foo(const std::vector<char>& input) {
    // Because you know the structure ahead of time, you can simply reverse the process
    // Here, I'll use memcpy to show how that's used too
    foo datafoo;
    memcpy( datafoo.a, input.data(), sizeof(datafoo.a) );
    // Offset by 4 (which is the typical size of an int
    memcpy( datafoo.b, input.data() + sizeof(datafoo.a), sizeof(datafoo.b) );
    // Now, we offset by 8, and each byte represents a character
    // We can memcpy into a std::string's data and null-terminate it as needed
    // By calling resize and telling it it's as big as the leftover data
    // minus the size of the other structures
    int offset = ( sizeof(datafoo.a) + sizeof(datafoo.b) );
    int csize = input.size() - offset;
    datafoo.c.resize( csize );
    memcpy( datafoo.c.input.data(), input.data() + offset, csize );
    // Usually, you don't use memcpy with strings, 
    // but this should do exactly as you want
    return datafoo;
}
```

This should not "waste any bytes or space", as you requested, but please remember that you should probably use `std::vector<char>` as your storage if you want a Binary Representation. Also, look into things like [protobuff](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) and other such data-packing and data-transfer protocols. You can use std::string above as well, but just keep in mind that using a std::string with some modifications above will make that string not behave very well with a lot of programs and routines, because `strings` are expected to be null-terminated, and the binary representations of numbers in C++ will royally screw that over for you.

Comment: You mean `vector.insert(vector.end(), adata, adata + sizeof(input.a));` and similar replacements for the other loops, right?

Comment: @DeadMG Indeed. Both will have the same effect, I'm sure, but I wanted to be explicit for the OP. Will add as an edit, however.